# How to set TextBlock background color for HighContrast Theme in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, themes, high-contrast

In Microsoft UWP application I tried to set a TextBlock background color using Grid in XAML. It was okay for default theme. But When I enable HighContrast Theme, only the Filled Text portion is black color; while remaining portion of the TextBlock is changed according to HighContrast Theme. I also tried with Border but the problem still occurs. I also tried with Style property, same issue.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

```
<Grid Height="50" Width="500" Background="{ThemeResource SystemColorHighlightColor}">
        <TextBlock Text="High Contrast" Width="250" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

[image: Check the output image if you want a clear vision]

[Comparison with system behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppeBr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to set c color for HighContrast Theme in UWP

The above behavior is by-design, and the `TextBlock` background was controlled by system. If you want to edit it, please go **Setting** page to find **High contrast Setting**  -> **Background**. And edit `Background` will change `TextBlock` background in `HighContrast` model.

[image]

And if you want to make Grid has same color, please keep `Selected Text` color same as Background color.

**Update**

In general, we often set the Grid background as `ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush` that could keep the the textblock background same as the Grid, then avoid the show the black block.

```
<Grid
    Width="500"
    Height="50"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    >
    <TextBlock
        Width="250"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="20"
        SelectionChanged="TextBlock_SelectionChanged"
        Text="High Contrast"
        />
</Grid>
```

**Update 1**

Please check TextBlock  [`HighContrastAdjustmen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.highcontrastadjustment?view=winrt-19041) property. if we set it as **None** , the black block will dismiss.

```
<Grid
    Width="500"
    Height="50"
    Background="{ThemeResource SystemColorHighlightColor}"
    >
    <TextBlock
        Width="250"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontSize="20"
        Foreground="Black"
        HighContrastAdjustment="None"
        Text="High Contrast"
        Visibility="Visible"
        />
</Grid>
```

Comment: then how the Windows 10 features (Setttings, File Explorer) and default app (Skype, Paint 3D) are showing well without modifying High Contrast Settings? they are not using any TextBlock!!!!! if used then how they are handling this situation!!

Comment: Yep, I know that, because you set the Grid background as `SystemColorHighlightColor`, so you need edit the color manually in setting page. In general, we often set the Grid  background `ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush` that could keep the the block background same as the Grid when you enable HighContrast Theme.

Comment: Thanks for your response :-) but if I want to keep TextBlock inside a Grid/StackPanel/RelativePanel and change the Textblock color according to the parent control, is it possible? and I want to change the color aligned with SystemColorHighlightColor . is it possible to work in any way around?

Comment: As you known, TextBlock does not contain Background color property that means we can't edit with code. And specify the Grid background as `SystemColorHighlightColor` is not good practice to implement dynamic system color. we suggest use `ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush` to replace.

Comment: I have added another image to my question "Comparison with system behavior". Left side is the system behavior, you know already. & right side is my output after your code. Actually I want same as left side system behavior; "When selected, Text Color will be Black and Background color will be received from system". Can you please help me to do this UI using TextBlock?

Comment: Sure, please check TextBlock  [`HighContrastAdjustmen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.highcontrastadjustment?view=winrt-19041) property. if we set it as none, the black block will dismiss.